# laravel 5 routing error on live server

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5

I have recently moved my laravel 5 app to a live server. But I can only view my homepage. For example, i can view this page `example.laravel.com` but whenever I try to click register button it shows me an 404 error being `example.laravel.com/register`. But if I enter like `example.laravel.com/index.php/register`, i can view the register view without any `css`. What might be the possible problem? 
this is my .htaccess right now.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `mod-rewrite` is not enabled on your server.

On Ubuntu you can enable `mod-rewrite` by following simple steps,

Activate the `mod_rewrite` module with

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and restart the apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

To use `mod_rewrite` from within `.htaccess` files (which is a very common use case), edit the default VirtualHost with

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Search for “DocumentRoot /var/www/html” and add the following lines directly below:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Restart the server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This should solve your problem.